# How to properly design this concurrent execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

## Context

python 3.11

I have an PysimpleGUI app that I use for stream-like processing of audio. With two main functions:

- `_start_adding` which is a `while True` loop that records audio for 5 seconds (I/O operation), get the frames of the recording then sends it to a queue
- `_start_processing` which is a `while True loop based on queue iterator` that receives a message from the Queue and does some CPU computation. Processing frames is always faster than recording them. I.e for 5 seconds recording I process in 2-3 seconds.

My current approach was to have both of them in separate threads (So the UI does not get stuck) but I then realized that I probably need to use parallelism since the `_start_processing` thread could delay the loop iteration of the recording thread and I would have gaps in audio.

```py
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


class ClosableQueue(Queue):
    SENTINEL= object()
    def close(self):
        self.put(self.SENTIEL)
    
    def __iter__(self) -> Message:
        while True:
            item = self.get()
            try:
                if item is self.SENTINEL:
                    return
                yield item
            finally:
                self.task_done()

class StoppableWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable, queue: ClosableQueue, args):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.queue = queue
        self.args = args
    
    def run(self):
        for item in self.queue:
            if item is self.queue.SENTINEL:
                return
            self.func(item)


def _start_adding():
    global stop_game_thread, message_queue
    chunk_time = 5
    while True:
        if stop_game_thread:
            message_queue.close()
            break
        frames = record.record_frames_for_seconds(seconds=chunk_time)
        message_queue.put(frames)


def _start_processing(message: Message):
    frames = message
    do_cpu_operation_for_2_seconds(


message_queue = ClosableQueue()
adding_thread = Thread(target=_start_adding)
processing_thread = StoppableWorker(_start_processing, message_queue)
```

## Question:

What options and which is the best option to solve this problem so that `_start_adding` keeps recording uninterrupted? Would a coroutine be a better choice for the `_start_adding`?

### My idea

Make either of them into a separate process to allow `_start_recording` run uninterrupted (delayed by the time it takes to send frames to the queue)

Comment: Whether you need multiprocessing (a separate process instead of a thread or some async solution) depends on the audio recording library you're using. If the recording operation is blocking, you're right. However, it seems more like that you can await the result of the recording asynchronously. In that case you need neither threads nor multiple processes, but you can just process and await in a simple loop.

Comment: nit, typo: Please spell it "SENTINEL".

Comment: Grismar - thanks for reply. The recording isn’t blocking but the processing is. Could you be more specific on what you meant by „process and await in a simple loop”? Isn’t what you suggest prone to a situation where the recording could be blocked by processing thread.

Comment: I would instrument and measure your code to see exactly what's happening so that you're not solving a problem that may not exist.  If one core isn't enough power, then multi-processing, as you mentioned, is a good direction.  It comes at the expense of complexity though.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Seems like you and @Grismar suggest something similar. I a noob and since I am new to concurrent programming this question might be stupid but: how could one core solve that problem? Is there thread balancing magic going on that would take GIL from `_start_processing` whenever `_start_adding` would be done with I/O since the recording thread occupies less GIL time than processing thread? Edit: I just realized its you you, big thanks for the PysimpleGUI!!!

Comment: I don't have a design to give you but rather a very broad explanation that nothing beats running tests and seeing what's actually happening on the computer, versus on paper.  I Would "See where you're at" with an initial design. Check latencies. See if you under-run or over-run anywhere.  It's how I did things in the embedded products and has worked out for the python ones too. Thank you for the kind words.... big welcome back....it's always great to see what's being built.

Comment: I re-read your concerns. I cannot imagine you're running realtime recording at an incredibly low level such there there is zero buffering going on below your code.  the way to find out is to run your code and iterate to get to your solution. Each run, you learn a little new thing. That gets incorporated into your thinking/design.  Make a change, try more runs.  Eventually you arrive at a solution.

Comment: Thanks, great suggestions! I guess I didn't test if the gaps appear and I should had - I just had "aha!" moment and realized that in theory the audio loop can be delayed by processing of the message. For now I will increase recording time to 10 seconds and  I will delay the Queue message delivery to  the processing thread to allow recording thread to start next iteration: Record 1-> Send 1(Queue sleeps (I/O, GIL free) -> Record 2 -> Receive 1 -> Process 1 -> Send 2 (Queue sleeps) Record 3 -> Process 2....

Comment: On the application note: App is called "Shut up" and in a conversation it tracks the % of time each member of conversation was speaking for. I have a working prototype with okay/ish results. Before starting  the logic I take a short recording of each speaker and map it into a vector, then I start the 5 second recording and use a ready pipeline to perform Speaker diarisation. For all speakers In a 5 second audio chunk I get annonymous speaker embedding and the time they spoke for. I match the embeddings against the the closest embeddings that I generated prior to the game and update their time

Comment: The app motivation comes from a fact that I am a big extrovert who likes to speak but I would like to be considerate of my fellow conversation members and keep my occupation of a conversation to some % :D. For now I implemented the app so that it tracks all speakers but I consider pivoting to only perform a binary classification i.e. find the % of time I speak :D I have some mvp recordings on my google drive LMK if you would like to see :D

Comment: I implemented a delayed message delivery and set the chunk to 10 seconds,  there seem to be almost no gaps in the recordings!

Comment: Some comments: Since you are using a sentinel to represent the "no more frames" condition, there is no reason for calling `task_done` on the queue, which is only useful if you are *joining* the queue. You might as well use a `SimpleQueue` if you are using threading. Also, `ClosableQueue.__iter__` is not iterating the sentinel (nor should it) so `StoppableWorker.run` should not be checking for it.